# PHP: Scrape all numbers from Brackets "(123)"

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I have a HTML-Code. The structure is always the same. But i don't know, how i can extract all numbers from the brackets.

Example-Code:

```
    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="padding-right:0.5em;padding-bottom:1px;white-space:nowrap;font-size:10px;" align="left">
  <a href="#" style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;" target="_top">5 Sterne</a>:
</td>
<td style="min-width:60; background-color: #eeeecc" class="tiny" title="73%" align="left" width="60"><div style="background-color:#FFCC66; height:13px; width:73%;"></div></td>
<td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;;font-size:10px;" align="right">&nbsp;(96)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right:0.5em;padding-bottom:1px;white-space:nowrap;font-size:10px;" align="left">
  <a href="#" style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;" target="_top">4 Sterne</a>:
</td>
<td style="min-width:60; background-color: #eeeecc" class="tiny" title="11%" align="left" width="60"><div style="background-color:#FFCC66; height:13px; width:11%;"></div></td>
<td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;;font-size:10px;" align="right">&nbsp;(15)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right:0.5em;padding-bottom:1px;white-space:nowrap;font-size:10px;" align="left">
  <a href="#" style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;" target="_top">3 Sterne</a>:
</td>
<td style="min-width:60; background-color: #eeeecc" class="tiny" title="7%" align="left" width="60"><div style="background-color:#FFCC66; height:13px; width:7%;"></div></td>
<td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;;font-size:10px;" align="right">&nbsp;(10)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right:0.5em;padding-bottom:1px;white-space:nowrap;font-size:10px;" align="left">
  <a href="#" style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;" target="_top">2 Sterne</a>:
</td>
<td style="min-width:60; background-color: #eeeecc" class="tiny" title="3%" align="left" width="60"><div style="background-color:#FFCC66; height:13px; width:3%;"></div></td>
<td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;;font-size:10px;" align="right">&nbsp;(4)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right:0.5em;padding-bottom:1px;white-space:nowrap;font-size:10px;" align="left">
  <a href="#" style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;" target="_top">1 Stern<span style="color:#FFFFFF">e</span></a>:
</td>
<td style="min-width:60; background-color: #eeeecc" class="tiny" title="4%" align="left" width="60"><div style="background-color:#FFCC66; height:13px; width:4%;"></div></td>
<td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;;font-size:10px;" align="right">&nbsp;(6)</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><div style="width:60px;">&nbsp;</div></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

In this case i need this numbers: 96, 15, 10, 4 and 6.

Please give me a tip, which function is good for it.

Comment: You want to look at the DOMDocument feature of PHP.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('~\((\d+)\)~',$content,$numbers);
print_r($numbers); // example to print results
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (96)
            [1] => (15)
            [2] => (10)
            [3] => (4)
            [4] => (6)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 96
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DOM parser such as [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/dom) to parse the HTML document. Since the structure is always the same, you can simply traverse the DOM using an XPath expression and grab the text from the third `<td>` node. Once you have the node value, you can use a simple [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) to get the number:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//table/tbody/tr/td[3]/text()') as $node) {
    $number = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $node->nodeValue);
    echo $number . '<br/>';
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/76623)

Comment: THX! The DOM parser is very helpful for me :)